# How to change the link target in a entity reference display?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation, entities

I'm on d7. I have two content types on my site, "link" and "Article". The link content type contains a link field from the link module that users enter a link to another site in to. I have the "link" content type referenced (thanks to the entity reference module) in my "article" content type and I would like for the link, when clicked, to open the referring page (offsite) in a new tab/window. How can I do this?? Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure a link field to open in a new window.

About halfway down the edit page for your link field, you'll see 'Link Target,' and that's where you set it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add a simple jQuery script that adds `"target='_blank'` to the link field?

For example, if your link field ID is "field_link_und_0" (search it in the HTML source), in the node-XYZ.tpl.php template file you can add the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready({
    jQuery('#field_link_und_0').attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Comment: Or can use [External Links](http://drupal.org/project/extlink) module too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the real stuff:

just make this function in your template.php. It comes from file.module:

```
function **yourtheme**_file_link($variables) {

  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
      'attributes' => array(
          'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
          'target' => '_blank',
      ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there were two questions in one.

1. How to open the offsite URL in the referred node (Link) directly from the referring node (Article). For that, use the [Link Replace Filter](https://drupal.org/project/link_replace_filter) module.
2. How to open an offsite URL in a new browser tab — the easiest is to use for that is the [External Link](https://drupal.org/project/extlink) module.